# Purge single file cache from Azure CDN using query string

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I have an azure storage account + cdn + endpoint.

The content on a particular file rarely changes but when it does we'd like a non-technical team to be able to purge the cache for the file, without using the API or Powershell.

Can we purge the azure cdn cache for a single file using query string and cache rules engine?

Something like:

```
https://our-endpoint.azureedge.net/file.html?clearcache=true
```

Or alternatively could we use the rules engine to set the TTL for this file only to 1 second, and then afterwards set the TTL back to 604800 seconds (1 week)

```
https://our-endpoint.azureedge.net/file.html?setTTL=1
https://our-endpoint.azureedge.net/file.html?setTTL=604800
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not yet available for now and even no ETA has been shared. I would recommend you to post the feature request here in this [feedback section](https://feedback.azure.com) for its future availability.

Answer (score 0):

There is a purge button in Azure CDN endpoint:
[image]

once you click on it, enter /file.html & purge.

Alternatively, you can set "cache every unique url" to cache rules.
[image]